# Force Strong Password Generation

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, security, password

Is there any way to prompt iOS to generate a password when it doesn't detect a New Password/Change Password field?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great link from Cult Of Mac about how to use Siri to generate a secure password.   https://www.cultofmac.com/227362/use-siri-to-generate-a-super-secure-random-password-ios-tips/

Comment: The "Wolfram Password" process doesn't seem to work anymore.